# Is there a maven online option (override of offline in settings.xml)

Tags: maven

For various reasons (mostly speed and reliability* of build) I prefer to use maven in offline mode. As I don't like having to type `-o` every time (and deal with problems when I forget it), I've added `<offline>true</offline>` to my `.m2/settings.xml`.

However, sometimes I have to build online. Is there a command-line option for this, or any decent way of doing it without having to edit `settings.xml` and restoring it after the build?

* Why offline helps reliability in my case - the project consists of several maven projects, each with a set of submodules, so it requires running seveal `mvn` commands in sequence, each taking quite some time to build.. As all of those are automatically built on Jenkins, without offline sometimes later builds contact company maven repository and fetches artifacts that were built just during my local build, and I end up with a local build that does not contain my changes.

Comment: Can you explain why you need offline mode for `reliability of build`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the question. I don't think that will affect the answer though ;)

Comment: Can you more in detail explain why you need several `mvn` commands in sequence to build your product?

Comment: @khmarbaise There are several parent pom's, each one in a different git repo, each one with a bunch of submodules. And a separate `mvn` command is needed to actually deploy it to a server -- for some reason, I don't know why, it doesn't work when run with the main build.